# express.js apache configure on subdomain issue with pm2

Tags: node.js, express

I am using apache on aws with latest version of express.js framework.
I have added a subdomain on server.Also i am using pm2 package to run the
express
For example
grouplpha.domain.com

I am using running the command

```
pm2 start app.js
```

it is working fine but when I load the domain grouplpha.domain.com
it sa 403 permission issue.
default index.html is working fine.
Do I need to have additional configuration
on server to make it work or am I missing any?